# Obtaining youtube user profile using WebService::GData::YouTube fails

Tags: perl, youtube-api

I am trying to learn how to use [`WebService::GData::YouTube`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WebService::GData::YouTube) by following the tutorial at http://perlmaven.com/fetching-data-from-youtube-using-perl :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use WebService::GData::YouTube;
my $yt = WebService::GData::YouTube->new();
my $p = $yt->get_user_profile('Gabor Szabo');
print "ok\n";
```

But this fails with output:

```
WebService::GData::Error=HASH(0x1c45dc8)
```

The exception occurs in `$yt->get_user_profile()`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebService::GData::YouTube` uses the YouTube API v2, which has now been deprecated. You will need to use a library that works with v3 of the API.

Comment: Ok I will take your word for it, since the error message gives no clue about this being the case :) Do you know of any alternatives to `WebService::GData` ?

Comment: Details that the library is accessing v2 can be seen here: https://metacpan.org/pod/WebService::GData::YouTube#NAME

Comment: I don't know of a new Perl library for this I am afraid. There are client libraries for most other languages here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries. Sorry I can't be more help on the Perl side though.

Comment: Well volunteered to build one @HåkonHægland! :)